# Capture and Show Video from IP camera source (Unity3d + c#)

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, ip-camera, mjpeg

Need your help.
I am making simple application (and I'm a new to Unity3d also), which takes video from IP-camera and displays it onto Texture2D.
Video format is MJPG.
For simple jpg-images the code below works fine, but when I try to display MJPG I just get gray screen.

Did I make a mistake in code?

```
public class testVid : MonoBehaviour {

    //public string uri = "http://24.172.4.142/mjpg/video.mjpg"; //url for example
    public Texture2D cam;
    public void Start() {
        cam = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        StartCoroutine(Fetch());
    }

    public IEnumerator Fetch() {
        while(true) {
            Debug.Log("loading... " + Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            WWW www = new WWW("http://24.172.4.142/mjpg/video.mjpg");
            yield return www;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
                throw new UnityException(www.error);
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(cam);
        }
    }
    public void OnGUI() {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), cam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15580

- Add the script to a game object
- Set the URL of the video in the script
- Create a new material of Unlit 2D
- Add this material to the movie script in the inspector
- Then assign the same material to the game object you
  want to display the video (e.g. a quad)

Hope it helps